# Subclass Type as closure parameter

Tags: swift, firebase, generics

**Usecase**

I have a superclass (FirebaseObject) with subclasses for most data items in my Firebase (ex: RecipeItem, User). I made a function in the superclass that automatically updates the data that is in the subclass, now I am trying to make a function with closures that get called when the object is updated.

---

**Code**

```
class FirebaseObject {
    private var closures: [((FirebaseObject) -> Void)] = []

    public func didChange(completion: @escaping (((FirebaseObject) -> Void))) {
        // Save closures for future updates to object
        closures.append(completion)

        // Activate closure with the current object
        completion(self)
    }

    //...
}
```

This calls the closure with the initial object and saves it for later updates. In my Firebase observer I can now activate all the closures after the data is updated by calling:

```
self.closures.forEach { $0(self) }
```

To add these closures that listen for object changes I need to do:

```
let recipeObject = RecipeItem(data)

recipeObject.didChange { newFirebaseObject in
    // Need to set Type even though recipeObject was already RecipeItem 
    // this will never fail
    if let newRecipeObject = newFirebaseObject as? RecipeItem {
        // Do something with newRecipeObject
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

Is there a way to have the completion handler return the type of the subclass so I don't have to do `as? Subclass` even though it won't ever fail? I tried to do this with generic type but I can't figure it out and I am not sure if this is the correct solution.

I would like to keep most code in the FirebaseObject class so I don't need to add a lot of code when creating a new subclass.

---

**Edit**

Based on [this article](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-what-are-protocols-with-associated-types/) I tried to add the type when creating a subclass:

```
class RecipeItem: FirebaseObject<RecipeItem> {
    //...
}

class FirebaseObject<ItemType> {
    private var handlers: [((ItemType) -> Void)] = []  

    public func didChange(completion: @escaping (((ItemType) -> Void))) {
        //...
```

This compiles but it crashes as soon as RecipeItem is initialised. I also tried

```
class RecipeItem: FirebaseObject<RecipeItem.Type> {
    //...
}
```

But this gives an interesting compiler error when I try to access RecipeItem data in `didChange` closure:

> Instance member 'title' cannot be used on type 'RecipeItem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've been working on this for a day and I have found a way to do it using the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39583073/3393964) for the didChange and initObserver functions and taking inspiration from [this way of saving data in extensions](https://github.com/BayPhillips/draggable-swift/pull/2/commits/4aee33df7c3b53465701f4d5fe9811b2bca33576).

First off, all the functions that need to use the type of the subclass are moved to a protocol.

```
protocol FirebaseObjectType {}

extension FirebaseObjectType where Self: FirebaseObject {
    private func initObserver(at ref: DatabaseReference) {
        //...
    }

    mutating func didChange(completion: @escaping (((Self) -> Void))) {
        if observer == nil {
            // init Firebase observer here so there will be no Firebase
            // observer running when you don't check for changes of the
            // object, and so the Firebase call uses the type of whatever
            // FirebaseObject this function is called on eg:
            //    RecipeItem.didChange returns RecipeItem
            // and NOT:
            //    RecipeItem.didChange returns FirebaseObject
            initObserver(at: ref)
        }
        if closureWrapper == nil {
            // init closureWrapper here instead of in init() so it uses
            // the class this function is called on instead of FirebaseObject
            closureWrapper = ClosureWrapper<Self>()
        }

        // Save closure for future updates to object
        closures.append(completion)

        // Activate closure with current object
        completion(self)
    }
}
```

To save the closures I now use a wrapper class so I can do type checking on that. In FirebaseObject:

```
class ClosureWrapper<T> {
    var array: [((T) -> Void)]

    init() {
        array = []
    }
}

fileprivate var closureWrapper: AnyObject?
```

Now I can get the closures with the right type in FirebaseObjectType protocol:

```
private var closures: [((Self) -> Void)] {
    get {
        let closureWrapper = self.closureWrapper as? ClosureWrapper<Self>

        return closureWrapper?.array ?? []
    }
    set {
        if let closureWrapper = closureWrapper as? ClosureWrapper<Self> {
            closureWrapper.array = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I can now use didChange on a FirebaseObject subclass without checking its type every time.

```
var recipe = RecipeItem(data)

recipe.didChange { newRecipe in
    // Do something with newRecipe 
}
```